# How to add an ItemsSource to a DataGrid from a async Task

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have WPF application with a Datagrid. I want to be able to run a code that retrieves data from certain location every X time and updates the DataGrid ItemsSource. The code can't interfere with UI, so it needs to run as async. I started to test the basics and yet I haven't been successful. My test compiles, but the following Exception is thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll.

I would like someone to share a simple approach to solve what I think should be a simple problem.

```
public void runTask()
{

    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    int counter = 0;

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            list.Add(counter.ToString());
            MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;   // This is what I want to archive
            counter++;                       // but I get this: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll

            // Wait 2 seconds
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            runTask();

        }
    }
}

// User starts the async task
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            runTask();
        }
```

Comment: use observable collection, instead setting it every time set it only once on right thread (outside Action passed to Task.Run)... in the loop only add to the collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your example is a toy example, so I'll just focus on the exception. It happens because the task is running on a different thread to the UI and you cannot update UI controls from a non-UI thread.

To interact with the UI from a non-UI thread, you use the Dispatcher:

```
// inside the non-UI thread
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => 
{
    MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
});
```

Comment: Great answer pal, just what i needed. I knew It should be simple.